# Create Team meeting on behalf of a user using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Am trying to create a meeting for a user using my application, I have successfully signing the user and requested for the right permission but when I call me/events and add teamsforbusiness I don't get the meeting link but I get it when i try Skypeforbusiness. I have also tried using /me/onlineMeetings endpoint but getting this error

> Error authenticating with resource
> Endpoint

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v2.0/me/onlineMeetings
```

my scope

```
  appScopes: [
'openid',
'offline_access',
'profile',
'User.Read',
'MailboxSettings.Read',
'Calendars.ReadWrite',
'OnlineMeetingArtifact.Read.All,',
'OnlineMeetings.Read',
'OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite',
```

]

Meeting data

```
{
  "startDateTime":"2019-07-12T14:30:34.2444915-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2019-07-12T15:00:34.2464912-07:00",
  "subject":"User Token Meeting"
}
```

Response

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request), the endpoint should like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings
```

But you used `v2.0` here.